# Show that the equation $x^n=f(x)$ has one positive root

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Show that the equation $x^n=f(x)$ where $f(x)$ is a polynomial with positive coefficients of degree $n-1$, has only one positive root.

I found this problem but I'm having trouble solving it and I would really like some help.

I thought proof by contradiction by assuming that we have at least two positive roots that satisfy the equation but I don't really know where to go from there.

Sorry for any mistakes in my English. It's not my native language

Comment: @NoChance $f(x)$ is supposed to have +ve coeffs

Comment: @OK, thanks for the remark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is (a particular case of) [Descartes' rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs)

Since $x^n-f(x)$ has exactly one sign change, the number of positive real roots is either 1 or an odd number less than 1. This means it has exactly 1 positive root.

You can find a proof for example [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/descartes-rule-of-signs/), or many other places

Comment: I think that the sign of the constant term must be considered. For example $x^3-2x^2+1=0$ has  2 positive roots, (1 and 1.618) whereas  $x^3-2x^2-1=0$ has only 1 positive root of value 2.206 (assuming no complex roots).

Comment: @NoChance What do you mean? In $$x^3=2x^2-1=:f(x)$$ $f(x)$ does not have positive coefficients. The constant term is the coefficient of $x^0$, it is still called a coefficient.

Comment: You are correct, thank you for your reply.

Comment: @NoChance No problem...

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x)=x^n -f(x)$.  Let $M$ be the number of positive roots of $g(x)$. Observe that $g(0)=-k$ where $k>0$ is constant term in $f(x)$ . Also $lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}g(x)\rightarrow\infty$ so there is at least one root in $(0,\infty)$ which sets the lower bound for $M$ i.e. $M\ge 1$.

Descarte's rule of sign changes in $g(x)$ sets the upper bound for $M$ i.e. $M\le 1$. So $M=1$.

Furthermore, if $f(x)$ doesn't have a constant term then $g(x)=x^r.h(x)$ where $g(x)$ has a root at $x=0$ with multiplicity $r$. You can work along the same lines on $h(x)$ now.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

It's enough to show that 
$$1=\frac{f(x)}{x^n}$$
has one root in $(0,\infty)$. Note that the RHS is decreasing.